# Cayley table for the additive and mutiplicative operations in ($\Bbb F_7$, +, *)

Tags: finite-fields, cayley-table

I am to construct the Cayley tables for the additive and multiplicative operation in $(\Bbb F_7, +, *)$. I have started by stating

> The order (nr of elements) of a finite field must be a prime or prime power. $\Bbb F_7$ is a finite field with 7 elements, and any polynomial $g \in \Bbb F_7$ can be uniquely written as $g=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+fq$ for some $q \in \Bbb F_7$, and some $a_0,a_1,a_2 \in \Bbb F_7$

Previusly I have constructed Cayley tables for groups $G=(\Bbb Z_n, operation)$, is constructing the table for fields the same? If not, how do they differ? How can I construct this table when I know how to construct the table for f.ex. $(\Bbb Z_7, +)$ or $(\Bbb Z_7, *)$?

Edit:

I have understood that the tables for $(\Bbb F_7, +)$ is the same as the table for $(\Bbb Z_7, +)$, so now I'm wondering what the point of this exercise was. What am I supposed to learn from it? I had the impression I had to do some kind og plynomial division or something, but if the tables are the same I'm confused.

I have written the following:

> The tables for $(\Bbb F_7, +, *)$ is the same as the table for $(\Bbb Z_7, +)$
> $$
> \begin{array}{c|clr}
> + & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
> \hline
> 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
> 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 \\
> 2 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 \\
> 3 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 \\
> 4 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
> 5 & 5 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
> 6 & 6 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
> \end{array}
> \quad
> \begin{array}{c|clr}
> * & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
> \hline
> 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> 1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 \\
> 2 & 0 & 2 & 4 & 6 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
> 3 & 0 & 3 & 6 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 4 \\
> 4 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 5 & 2 & 6 & 3 \\
> 5 & 0 & 5 & 3 & 1 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
> 6 & 0 & 6 & 5 & 4 & 3 & 2 & 1 \\
> \end{array}
> $$

But how do I show that this differ from the table for $(\Bbb Z_7, +)$? Because I have just used the tables I already calculated in the previous exercise where i calculated the tables for $(\Bbb Z_7, +)$ and $(\Bbb Z_7, *)$. How can I mathematically show that these are table for $(\Bbb F_7, +)$ and $(\Bbb F_7, *)$? If I write something like "The tables are the same as for those of $(\Bbb Z_7, +)$ and $(\Bbb Z_7, *)$", I haven't really done anything in this exercise. I am missing something that shows that my solution is for fields. Or do you think I'm overthinking this? I don't think I am, it just seems too easy to just copy the tables.

Comment: But $\Bbb F_7$ *is* $\Bbb Z_7$.

Comment: Yes, but is the table for $( \Bbb F_7, +)$ the same as the table for $(\Bbb Z_7, +)$?

Comment: Absolutely the same (and also for multiplication).

Comment: Thank you! But why is this? What am I missing?